# How do you populate database in Play framework?

Tags: java, database, playframework, ebean

What is your way of populating database in Play framework?

We tried to write custom evolution script to do that, but it ended up not being very good solution.

Do you have some java code running on application startup that does that for you, for example by using ORM (like Ebean)?

Thank you very much.